# How to disable the new inspector tooltip in the devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the latest Chrome version (73.0.3683.86) there is a new feature which adds a tooltip to the Inspector tool which shows information about the hovered element. (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQCSG.png))

The question now is whether someone has already found out if this function can be disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Very annoying. I don't believe you can disable it at the moment but if you hold down Ctrl/Cmd you can move around the page without it showing up.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me crazy lately.